# How to categorize 47 nlevels?

Tags: r

I am very new to R programming and programming in general. Currently working on a small project.

I have 47 different 'job titles' in a column named "Work_Titles" and I want to group them to "emp_class".

For eg: all job titles named:

```
"VP Human Resources", "VP Finance", "CEO" -> emp_class "Excecutive_Titles"
                             
"Meats Manager", "Stores Manager", "Produce Manager" -> emp_class "cL_managers"
```

Plan is to after categorizing them, I would like to

- give them a standard salary for each "emp_class"
- find out how many "terminations" have been happening in each "emp_class".

Any kind of help and advice is very much welcome as I am totally lost.

Comment: How does your data structure look like? Please make a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) or [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with a sample input and your expected output. This is needed to create, test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: This is simple to do once you have made a list of all the job titles and their assigned class (two columns).